# Get the value of the variable url to iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I would like to help see the example:

```
http://www.siteexemple.com/pagina.php?url=http://www.variablevalue.com
```

In my php: pagina.php I have the iframe:

```
 <Iframe src = "" width = "100%" height = "100%" scrolling = "no" frameborder = "0" allowFullScreen = "true"> </ iframe>
```

Now how do I get the value of the variable `` url`to the iframe src = ""`

the result I would like to get is:

```
 <Iframe src = "http://www.variablevalue.com" width = "100%" height = "100%" scrolling = "no" frameborder = "0" allowFullScreen = "true"> </ iframe>
```

Already tried:

```
 <Iframe src = "<? Php echo $ url;?>" Width = "100%" height = "100%" scrolling = "no" frameborder = "0" allowFullScreen = "true"> </ iframe>
```

But it did not work, I thank you in advance for attention thank you!

Comment: use javascript to get src

Comment: where did you define `$url` in the php?

Answer (score 0):

Use $_GET["url"] instead of $url.

```
<Iframe src = "<?php echo $_GET["url"]; ?>" Width = "100%" height = "100%" scrolling = "no" frameborder = "0" allowFullScreen = "true"> </ iframe>
```

Just a note that if you contain un-encoded URL as variables might cause some escape exceptions. I'll suggest to use urlencode() and urldecode() to process these variants in advance.